# Is there a way to check if msg.sender owns some collection?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, erc721

Is there a way to do the following:

```
function registerCollection(address __collection) public {
        require(msg.sender == IERC721(__collection).owner), "Does not own contract");
        ...[rest of function]...
}
```

Is there a way, within solidity, to access the owner field of another contract. So I do not mean owns an NFT of another collection, which could be done by calling .ownerOf(tokenId) and comparing to msg.sender. I want to get the actual owner of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a collection has a `address public owner`, especially if it inherits from Openzeppelin's Ownable library.
So you are able to get it like this:

```js
interface IOwnable {
  function owner() external view returns(address)
}

IOwnable(__collection).owner()
```

Though be aware that if a collection doesn't gave a public `owner` the call will revert.